# I roll a 6 sided dice 5 times what are the odds #6 comes up 5 times if I get 3 rerolls and get to keep the 6 when it is rolled each time, Ex. 2+1+2

Tags: probability-theory

What is the probability if I roll a 6-sided dice 5 times to get all 5 dice to land with the #6 if the person gets 3 rerolls and gets to keep the #6 when it is rolled each time,  For example, 1st Roll-If the person gets a #6 the first time they roll the dice then they can continue on and the one (1) die they rolled with #6 is kept.
2nd Roll -If the person gets another (2) dice with the #6 on them then they get to keep the (2) dice for a total of (3) dice now with the #6.
3rd Roll- The person gets (2) more dice with a #6.

What is the probability a person will get all 6's if they roll a 6-sided dice up to 3 times  keeping the 6s they rolled each time and then rolling the remaining dice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community The question is clear as stated.

Comment: Please ignore the Community Bot comment.  The question that you are posting, although somewhat wordy, is clear.  I see no ambiguity in the Math problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.

Comment: Minor clarification requested.  I infer that you, the OP (i.e. original poster) actually intend that (in effect) initially you are rolling $(5)$ separate dice, once each.  Any of the $(5)$ dice that show a **six** are left as is, and the other dice are then re-rolled.  You are allowed **two** additional **re-rolls**, for a total of three rolls, if necessary.  Please confirm that my inference represents the Math problem that you are trying to solve.